# rendering dataframe of pandas in django template

Tags: django, pandas, django-templates

I want to render dataframe of pandas with classes into django template. Please find below code.

```
{% autoescape off %}
  {% surface_data.nu.to_html classes="table bg-light table-striped table-hover table-sm" %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

where surface_data.nu is the dataframe.
using https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html?highlight=to_html

I have other methods to that. I just wanted to check is there any efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have read some articles and found best way to do with custom tags as following:

> Python, django

```
@register.filter(needs_autoescape=True)
@register.simple_tag()
def pd_html(pd, *args, **kwargs):
    classes = kwargs['classes']
    return pd.to_html(classes=classes,index=False)
```

In the template, I have added the following code.

```
    {% autoescape off %}
      <h6>Heat Transfer</h6>
      {% pd_html surface_data.nu classes="table table-bordered table-striped table- 
       hover table-sm"%}
  {% endautoescape %}
```

Where surface_data.nu is dataframe and classes are bootstrap table classes. I assume that one's is using bootstrap for styling.
I hope that, it may help some one.